# Get count of orders that is closed in less than 30 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns the following output

**Output**

```
OutletID    Avg Receive  Avg Ready  Avg Dispatch   Avg Close       Customers           Orders
32            58           29           0             200              6               6
23            27           1            0              3               7               3
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT
  Outlets.OutletID,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) AS [Avg Receive],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate)) AS [Avg Ready],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate)) AS [Avg Dispatch],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate)) AS [Avg Close],
  Count (dbo.Orders.CustomerID) as Customers,
  Count (dbo.Orders.OrderID)  as Orders
FROM dbo.Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReceivedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReadyOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReadyOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.DispatchedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.DispatchedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ClosedOrders.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/Dec/2017 10:00 AM' AND '05/Dec/2017 12:00 am'
and dbo.Orders.OrderID not in (select OrderID from [dbo].[CanceledOrders])
GROUP BY Outlets.OutletID,
         Brands.BrandName,
         dbo.Outlets.OutletName
ORDER BY dbo.Outlets.OutletName, Brands.BrandName
```

what i am looking for is to get count of orders that is closed under 30 minutes for each outlet so the output should be like below.

**Desired Output**

```
OutletID    Avg Receive  Avg Ready  Avg Dispatch   Avg Close       Customers           Orders   lessthan30
32            58           29           0             200              6               6           4
23            27           1            0              3               7               3           2
```

The query to get the difference between closing time and order time

```
    SELECT
  COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS [less30]
FROM [dbo].[Orders]
INNER JOIN dbo.ClosedOrders
  ON dbo.ClosedOrders.[OrderID] = Orders.OrderID
WHERE [OrderStatus] = 'Closed'
AND DATEDIFF(mi, Orders.OrderDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate) < 30
AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN  '01/Dec/2017 10:00 AM' AND '05/Dec/2017 12:00 am'
```

So how can i combine the tow queries into one query

Comment: Please do not code dump your entire query. Instead, fabricate and post the simplest query using the simplest schema you can think of that shows the problem. Specifically, remove most (and if possible all) of those joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have the exact schema but I think this should work

```
SELECT
  Outlets.OutletID,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) AS [Avg Receive],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate)) AS [Avg Ready],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate)) AS [Avg Dispatch],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate)) AS [Avg Close],
  Count (dbo.Orders.CustomerID) as Customers,
  Count (dbo.Orders.OrderID)  as Orders,
  count less30 as Closedin30
FROM dbo.Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReceivedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReadyOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReadyOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.DispatchedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.DispatchedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ClosedOrders.OrderID
  left join 
  (
    SELECT
    Orders.OrderID as less30
    FROM [dbo].[Orders]
        INNER JOIN dbo.ClosedOrders
    ON dbo.ClosedOrders.[OrderID] = Orders.OrderID
        WHERE [OrderStatus] = 'Closed'
    AND DATEDIFF(mi, Orders.OrderDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate) < 30
    AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN  '01/Dec/2017 10:00 AM' AND '05/Dec/2017 12:00 am'
  ) closedIntime
  on
  (
  dbo.Orders.OrderID = closedIntime.less30
  )
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '01/Dec/2017 10:00 AM' AND '05/Dec/2017 12:00 am'
and dbo.Orders.OrderID not in (select OrderID from [dbo].[CanceledOrders])
GROUP BY Outlets.OutletID,
         Brands.BrandName,
         dbo.Outlets.OutletName
ORDER BY dbo.Outlets.OutletName, Brands.BrandName
```